# Date is not converted into correct timestamp (unix_timestamp) using strtotime()

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I am converting date into timestamp i.e 2021-11-01 using strtotime() but it give me huge deffernce
I am getting timestame: 1635746400  which is the time 11/1/2021, 11:30:00 AM But it timestamp should be 1635705000 which means date should be consider from 12PM not no 11:30 AM

```
strtotime($startdate'); // date passed in variable: 2021-11-01
```

Comment: Timestamps are relative to UTC. Are you setting the timezone correctly?

Comment: my time zone is set denver. How I can set default time zone for custom script

Comment: Take a look at [date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: "Timestamps are relative to UTC" - Not sure what you mean by timestamp, but Unix time is an absolute date so it isn't bound to any time zone and other timestamp formats usually have an implicit or explicit time zone.